# "Acrobatic" and "fluid" combat system (i.e. Spider-Man 2018)

Tags: game-mechanics, combat

Like it says in the title, I like the way that Spider-Man Has a dynamic and fluid feeling combat system. I can't exactly put my finger on a few key aspects, though, and I don't have any way I can think of to recreate it in a game engine. Why does it feel good to play, and how could I apply that to my game?

Comment: This looks like a topic for an entire GDC talk or book chapter, or maybe even a whole book of its own. I'm not sure we can fit a reasonably complete answer to such a broad question in the format of a StackExchange post. Can you try to focus down on a specific mechanic or moment in gameplay that you want to try to implement? Then you can ask another question to layer the next mechanic onto that base, etc...

Comment: @DMGregory I guess I forgot to mention that I don't need much information, maybe just a link to a video or a starting point to research. Any information helps.

Comment: Link-only answers are discouraged here. Good StackExchange questions ask for an in-depth explanation, not just a link to an existing document.